# \multicolumn in a {tabu} with non-X columns

Tags: tabularx, multicolumn, tabu

In a `tabu` environment (`tabu` 2.8 package), I use `\multicolumn` to omit some cells' preamble (and occasionally span multiple columns). Unfortunately this breaks down the width calculations when there are non-X columns: if the `\multicolumn{1}{l}{TEXT}` is wider than the widest normal cell, the table as a whole becomes wider.

The manual mentions this as a known problem that can be fixed by including `\tabuphantomline`, but I'm not seeing any effect.

MNWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\begin{document}
This document illustrates difficulties with the \texttt{tabu} environment. All
tables are supposed to be \verb`\textwidth` wide, just like the present
paragraph.

\verb`tabularx` for reference: \\
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\ttfamily}lX}
  \hline
  foo & wibble \\
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{foo} & wibble \\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}

\verb`tabu` with a \verb`\multicolumn`: \\
\begin{tabu}{>{\ttfamily}lX}
  \hline
  foo & wibble \\
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{multicolumn} & wibble \\
  \hline
\end{tabu}

\verb`tabu` with a \verb`\multicolumn` and a \verb`\tabuphantomline`: \\
\begin{tabu}{>{\ttfamily}lX}
  \hline
  \tabuphantomline
  foo & wibble \\
  \tabuphantomline
  \multicolumn{1}{l}{multicolumn} & wibble \\
  \tabuphantomline
  \hline
\end{tabu}

\end{document}
```

[image: tabu-multicolumn-mwe.png]

How can I make `\multicolumn` work as desired (influencing the width of the column(s) that it replaces, but not the width of the table as a whole, as illustrated above with `tabularx`?)

Answer (score 1):

This problem only seems to arise when you're using a `\multicolumn` command and passing `1` to it as its first argument and using a non-X column type. Compare the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{parskip}

\begin{document}

This document illustrates difficulties with the \texttt{tabu} environment.
All tables are supposed to be \verb`\textwidth` wide, just like the present paragraph.

\verb`tabu` with a \verb`\multicolumn` and a \verb`\tabuphantomline`:

\begin{tabu}{>{\ttfamily}lX}
  \hline
  foo & wibble \\
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{multicolumn} & wibble \\
  \hline
  \tabuphantomline
\end{tabu}

\begin{tabu}{>{\ttfamily}llX}
  \hline
  foo & wibble & wobble \\
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{multicolumn} & wibble \\
  \hline
  \tabuphantomline
\end{tabu}

\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image]

So this appears to be a bug with how `\tabuphantomline` handles `\multicolumn`s with a width of `1` when there are non-X column types.

If you're just using `\multicolumn` with a width of `1` to change the horizontal alignment of a single cell, you could instead define a new macro called `\CenteredCell`, for example, and thereby avoid having to use `\multicolumn{1}...` and `\tabuphantomline`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{parskip}

\newcommand*{\CenteredCell}[1]{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}>{\rmfamily}c@{}}
    #1%
  \end{tabular}}

\begin{document}

This document illustrates difficulties with the \texttt{tabu} environment.
All tables are supposed to be \verb`\textwidth` wide, just like the present paragraph.

\verb`tabu` with a \verb`\multicolumn` and a \verb`\tabuphantomline`:

\begin{tabu}{>{\ttfamily}lX}
  \hline
  foo & wibble \\
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{multicolumn} & wibble \\
  \hline
  \tabuphantomline
\end{tabu}

\begin{tabu}{>{\ttfamily}lX}
  \hline
  foo & wibble \\
  \CenteredCell{multicolumn} & wibble \\
  \hline
\end{tabu}

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but that solution is completely specific to the toy example in the question. In the real world, I have more complex preambles that do more than alignment, some do all kinds of crazy things like index the content of the column. I really need that `\omit`.

Comment: @Gilles Fair enough. Figuring out what the bug is currently beyond me, I think, but perhaps this answer will prompt someone with more knowledge and time to look into it. Sorry this doesn't help for your use case.